# coding correction for flux ratios

Tags: python, numpy, math, append

I am new to coding. There was a senior who wrote this code and left. I am unable to contact him. The code is for taking the ratio of line measurements made in IR lab. The code is as follows. I need to calculate the ratio of
CIV/Lya; error in CIV/Lya
CIV/CIII; error in CIV/CIII
CIV/HeII; error in CIV/HeII
CIV/MgII; error in CIV/MgII

The program has to search for commomn JDs (i.e. same date of observation)and within that JD has to do this ratio calculation for the values present in the following link [data files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rzp8e5ui3ib1q61/AADuiVXY8ODfaQ9pmMGBlq8_a?dl=0)

```
import math
import os
import numpy
#print os.getcwd()

Input_file_1 = open("L58.txt",'r')
#Input_file_1 = 'lineflux.txt'
first_line=Input_file_1.readline()
first_line=Input_file_1.readline()
line_flux = []
line_flux.append([])
line_flux.append([])
line_flux.append([])
line_flux.append([])
line_flux.append([])
for line in Input_file_1.readlines():
    ywl = [value for value in line.split()]
    #print ywl
    line_flux[0].append(float(ywl[0]))
    line_flux[1].append(ywl[3])
    line_flux[2].append(float(ywl[4]))
    line_flux[3].append(float(ywl[5]))
    line_flux[4].append(float(ywl[6]))
sigma_alpha = 0
v1=0
v2=0
ele = set(line_flux[1])
#print ele
ref_line_flux=[]
ref_line_flux.append([])
ref_line_flux.append([])
ref_line_flux.append([])
ref_line_flux.append([])
for l in range(len(line_flux[0])):
    if line_flux[1][l] == 'CIII':
        ref_line_flux[0].append(line_flux[0][l]) # MJD
        ref_line_flux[1].append(line_flux[2][l]) # Number
        ref_line_flux[2].append(line_flux[3][l]) # Line flux
        ref_line_flux[3].append(line_flux[4][l]) # RMS Error
print(ref_line_flux[0])
line_ratio=[]
line_ratio.append([])
line_ratio.append([])
line_ratio.append([])
line_ratio.append([])
line_ratio.append([])
line_ratio.append([])
rms_line_ratio=[] # Delete or add the below command accordingly
rms_line_ratio.append([])
rms_line_ratio.append([])
rms_line_ratio.append([])
rms_line_ratio.append([])
rms_line_ratio.append([])
rms_line_ratio.append([])
mjd=[]
mjd.append([])
mjd.append([])
mjd.append([])
mjd.append([])
mjd.append([])
mjd.append([])
for l in range(len(line_flux[0])):
    for x in range(len(ref_line_flux[0])):
        if ref_line_flux[0][x] == line_flux[0][l]:
            if line_flux[1][l] == 'LyA': # Put 0 for LyA
        mjd[0].append(ref_line_flux[0][x])
                line_ratio[0].append(line_flux[3][l]/ref_line_flux[2][x])
                rms_line_ratio[0].append(((line_flux[4][l]/line_flux[3][l])**2 + (ref_line_flux[3][x]/ref_line_flux[2][x])**2)**0.5)
            if line_flux[1][l] == 'CIV': # Put 1 for CIV
        mjd[1].append(ref_line_flux[0][x])
                line_ratio[1].append(line_flux[3][l]/ref_line_flux[2][x])
                rms_line_ratio[1].append(((line_flux[4][l]/line_flux[3][l])**2 + (ref_line_flux[3][x]/ref_line_flux[2][x])**2)**0.5)
            if line_flux[1][l] == 'HeII':
        mjd[2].append(ref_line_flux[0][x])
                line_ratio[2].append(line_flux[3][l]/ref_line_flux[2][x])
                rms_line_ratio[2].append(((line_flux[4][l]/line_flux[3][l])**2 + (ref_line_flux[3][x]/ref_line_flux[2][x])**2)**0.5)
            if line_flux[1][l] == 'MgII':
        mjd[3].append(ref_line_flux[0][x])
                line_ratio[3].append(line_flux[3][l]/ref_line_flux[2][x])
                rms_line_ratio[3].append(((line_flux[4][l]/line_flux[3][l])**2 + (ref_line_flux[3][x]/ref_line_flux[2][x])**2)**0.5)
            if line_flux[1][l] == 'SiIV':
        mjd[4].append(ref_line_flux[0][x])
                line_ratio[4].append(line_flux[3][l]/ref_line_flux[2][x])
                rms_line_ratio[4].append(((line_flux[4][l]/line_flux[3][l])**2 + (ref_line_flux[3][x]/ref_line_flux[2][x])**2)**0.5)
            if line_flux[1][l] == 'Unknown':
        mjd[5].append(ref_line_flux[0][x])
                line_ratio[5].append(line_flux[3][l]/ref_line_flux[2][x])
                rms_line_ratio[5].append(((line_flux[4][l]/line_flux[3][l])**2 + (ref_line_flux[3][x]/ref_line_flux[2][x])**2)**0.5)

sigma_alpha = math.log(v1/v2)*((sigma_12/ B12 + sigma_alpha / B22)**0.5)
alpha = math.log(B1/B2)/math.log(v1/v2)
file=open("output.txt",  "w")
file.write('MJD\t Flux ratio-CIII\t Error Flux ratio-CIII\n')
for i in range(len(line_ratio[0])):
    file.write(str(mjd[0][i]) + "\t" +str(line_ratio[0][i]) + "\t" + str(rms_line_ratio[0][i]) + "\n")
file.write('\n')
file.write('MJD\t Flux ratio-CIV\t Error Flux ratio-CIV\n')
for i in range(len(line_ratio[1])):
    file.write(str(mjd[1][i]) + "\t" +str(line_ratio[1][i]) + "\t" + str(rms_line_ratio[1][i]) + "\n")
file.write('\n')
file.write('MJD\t Flux ratio-HeII\t Error Flux ratio-HeII\n')
for i in range(len(line_ratio[2])):
    file.write(str(mjd[2][i]) + "\t" +str(line_ratio[2][i]) + "\t" + str(rms_line_ratio[2][i]) + "\n")
file.write('\n')
file.write('MJD\t Flux ratio-MgII\t Error Flux ratio-MgII\n')
for i in range(len(line_ratio[3])):
    file.write(str(mjd[3][i]) + "\t" +str(line_ratio[3][i]) + "\t" + str(rms_line_ratio[3][i]) + "\n")
file.write('\n')
file.write('MJD\t Flux ratio-SiIV\t Error Flux ratio-SiIV\n')
for i in range(len(line_ratio[4])):
    file.write(str(mjd[4][i]) + "\t" +str(line_ratio[4][i]) + "\t" + str(rms_line_ratio[4][i]) + "\n")
file.write('\n')
file.write('MJD\t Flux ratio-Unknown\t Error Flux ratio-Unknown\n')
for i in range(len(line_ratio[5])):
    file.write(str(mjd[5][i]) + "\t" +str(line_ratio[5][i]) + "\t" + str(rms_line_ratio[5][i]) + "\n")
file.write('\n')
file.write('\n')
file.close()
```

The code does not work.

It stops when it reaches the line

```
if line_flux[1][l] == 'LyA': # Put 0 for LyA 

mjd[0].append(ref_line_flux[0][x])
```

Commenting out this line it will stop at the next command of the similar type.

This is the error when running it in terminal of ubuntu 16.04

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Kindly help

Comment: What was the question please? Does the code you have provided work or not work - how/why? What is the table at the end - is it correct or incorrect? Why have you given your data files as images - nobody can open and read them.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I was not able to add the data files in the content. First picture is how he output is supposed to come and the bottom picture is the data. Could you help me out in uploading the data here.  The code does not work. It stops when it reaches the line                                                                                                                             if line_flux[1][l] == 'LyA': # Put 0 for LyA
        mjd[0].append(ref_line_flux[0][x])

Comment: I think you can only add PNG/JPEG/GIF files on here, so most folk seem to use Dropbox or Google Drive to share other filetypes. Please put all details in your original question rather than in the comments area - just click `edit` under your question. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  I have updated the question and given a link to the files via dropbox according to your suggestion.